# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchvision.models.video'

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

I'm trying to import this :

```py
import torchvision.models.video as video
```

But it throws:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchvision.models.video'

I can import other models without any problems like :

```py
import torchvision.models as models

resnet = models.resnet18()
```

Any idea how this can happen?

Comment: what's the version of torchvision you are using?

Comment: the video support was added from torchvision 0.4 : https://github.com/pytorch/vision/releases

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall torch, torchvision, and torchaudio. Then install the packages from preview(Nightly) from the following link https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

```
> pip uninstall torch torchvision torchaudio

> pip install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu117 --no-cache-dir
```

[image]